# Is this a JSON string?

Tags: json

I am wondering about the code here. I don't know whether it is JSON or other language.

```
anyType {
      centerCode=001; 
      centerName=General Organization; 
      enableMap=0;
      resultCode=0;
      resultMessage=ok ;
      validateToken=04184ee4f02862f3227e5b5563ce5e93;
}
```

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: it is json, not jason.. :)

Comment: To validate/parse [JSON](http://goo.gl/gFvCT).

Comment: This is the correct format - **{
    "centerCode": "001",
    "centerName": "GeneralOrganization",
    "enableMap": "0",
    "resultCode": "0",
    "resultMessage": "ok",
    "validateToken": "04184ee4f02862f3227e5b5563ce5e93"
}**

Comment: The code in the question is *not* valid JSON

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: the code returned from webservice that related to Blackberry i need that code to use it at my mobile application so i didn't know is that JASON or other language

Comment: Do you have any details of the webservice, or how you call it? If it's a public service then there is probably documentation online. Posting your code is strongly encouraged for coding questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not JSON.

It looks similar to Candle Object Notation, though.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_(programming_language) for more information.